# How to save extended properties in jquery custom plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    $.fn.InitFixedGrid  = function (args) {
    },

    $.fn.FixedGridSizeChagned = function (args) {
        // Here, I have to find out each of FixedColumn number for abc_grid01 and abc_grid02
    }
})(jQuery);


// Call usages

$("#abc_grid01").InitFixedGrid( { FixedColumn: 1 } );
$("#abc_grid02").InitFixedGrid( { FixedColumn: 2 } );
$("#abc_grid02").FixedGridSizeChagned( { Order: 0 } );
```

This is my custom jquery plugin structure.

When FixedGridSizeChagned is called, I have to get number 2 for FixedColumn property.

How can I save this property and call it later?

Comment: I don't think it is a good design idea to have 1 plugin depending on another one... still if you want to have access then you can save the properties using the data api then you can access it via the data key

Comment: would it be good idea for performance?

Comment: I don't think there is any considerable performance impact...